# Are There Cases in Which Non-Render-Triggering Global Vars May Be Needed in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have global state working via Context/AppState/AppStateDispatch. I also have component state working via useState.

But there are times when it appears it might be helpful to avoid using these:

- We need immediate access to the value in the current function and can't wait for the next render to get it. Storing it via useState/AppStateDispatch would prevent the value from being accessible until the next render
- ...and, those same values are needed globally throughout the app
- ...and a useRef would be destroyed on component unmount

In that case, it seems like it might be appropriate to use a globally-available, non-render-causing object to hold state for these items.

It's pretty easy to implement... but it seems non-React-y. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this pretty extensively the past few days. Here are a few observations.

In my use case, I'm using an external webRTC service. Their code requires my app to install listeners for incoming calls, responses to publication of video streams, etc. The listers needs to access the component's webRTC-specific variables

At the same time, those variables can't be part of component state or app state, because when updated, their values won't be available until the next refresh, and the rest of the component needs to access them within the current render.

Using an application global var that is apart from React and doesn't trigger a refresh is, of course, kludgy.

Here's the approach I'm using at the moment. So far it appears to be helpful.

- Create an application-state object to store all variables related to my component's use of webRTC.
- Initialize it via a call to a function, `getWebRTCDefaults()`.
- On component mount, copy it from app state to a component-level variable. Note-- it is not in component state -- it's a component-level variable, accessible anywhere in the component.
- As such it can be updated anytime within the component and its values are immediately available throughout the component.
- When a call starts and ends -- and only then -- I use `React context dispatch` to update the app state object. I.e. I do not update that object via `useEffect` as that could cause unnecessary renders.

This approach seems to be helpful. I can unmount the component and when I remount it, it picks up where it left off -- the webRTC video is still running.